# Trying To Draw polyline Resulting in Error C# Web App

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, polyline

I am trying to draw polyline but there is some error in in overloading method which i can not get why it is resulting in error when i am doing it correctly... my code,

```
   private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
        {
            String Locations = "";
            String locations = "";
            foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
            {
                // bypass empty rows        
                if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                    continue;

                string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
                string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();
                double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(r["Latitude"]);
                double longitude =Convert.ToDouble(r["Longitude"]);
                var points = new List<GLatLng> {new GLatLng(latitude,longitude)};
                var polyline = new GPolyline(points); 
                // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record    
                Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
                locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GPolyline(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
            }

            // construct the final script
            js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2); 
                                " + Locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();
                              }
                            }
                            </script> ";
   js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2); 
                                " + locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();
                              }
                            }
                            </script> ";
}
```

now it is giving me error in script polyline does not exsis

Hopes for your reply ...

Comment: When i remove double qoutes with single quotes in "#ff0000"  by '#ff0000' it results error "Too many characters in character literal" ??

Comment: Because in C# single quotes are only used to designate a single character (e.g. 'A').  A string must be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use JavaScript syntax in C#.  I'm surprised your first line even compiles.

Comment: @All what is the problem now ? Polyline does not exsis

Comment: @ i have added it again now i am getting points as list but polyline is not drawing Please help..

Comment: you've created a variable polyline in your C# code, but then you try to reference it in your Javascript code - it doesn't exist in the Javascript code.

Comment: you should open up a new question for this problem rather than editing this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPolyline constructor requires a variable of the type `List<GLatLng>` and that's not what your are passing in.

You need to create your GLatLng values as a List:

```
var points = new List<GLatLng> { new GLatLng(59.6919, 17.8582),new GLatLng(59.3030, 18.0395),new GLatLng(58.9789, 17.5341) };
var polyline = new GPolyline(points,"#ff0000",1);
```

Comment: Post Edited please check it out