# Why polylines not know in jmelosegui google map control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm beginner in asp.net mvc and want to write simple web application for practice,show map and on the map show road map,for that purpose use the this tutorial and tools:
[this line](http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/Shapes/PolylineBasic)

but in this line:

```
.Polylines(pf => pf.Add()
```

i get this error:

```
Map Builder does not contain Polylines are you missing assembly?
```

how can i solve that ?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-V3-Draw-route-line-between-two-geographic-locations-Coordinates-Latitude-and-Longitude-points.aspx), you need to create your LatitudeLongitude values as a `List` to create polyline using asp.net.

```
var points = new List<GLatLng> { new GLatLng(59.6919, 17.8582),new GLatLng(59.3030, 18.0395),new GLatLng(58.9789, 17.5341) };
var polyline = new GPolyline(points,"#ff0000",1);
```

Check this related SO questions:

- [Trying To Draw polyline Resulting in Error C# Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035983/trying-to-draw-polyline-resulting-in-error-c-sharp-web-app)
- [MVC Google Map Polylines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147398/mvc-google-map-polylines)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem.
If you follow the official instructions and if you execute 
`Install-Package Jmelosegui.Mvc.Googlemap`
in PM Console, you will get version 0.8.0 installed which does not contain Polyline yet.

See: http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/

The author told on his GitHub page that you might need to install the newest beta version to get all new features. It is indeed confusing that he promotes already features there which are not officially released yet. A beta version is not a release version for me. ;-)

Therefore execute 
`Install-Package Jmelosegui.Mvc.Googlemap -Version 0.8.16-beta-gd2b2689432`
in PM Console, that new beta version contains Polyline.

More information: https://libraries.io/nuget/Jmelosegui.Mvc.Googlemap